# How to set up databases (tables) in Android to perform searches between them

Tags: android, database, sqlite, recipe

**EDIT**

I have learned that I might not need multiple databases, but multiple tables within that database.

**What I have now**
I am building an app that is going to deal with recipes. Currently, I have sort of a locker where you can add your items that you want in that locker. That could be, for example, a pack of minced beef or a loaf of bread or what not. I let the user add this in the app, depending on what they have in their locker/fridge/freezer. I am doing this, using SQLiteDatabase. Everything works the way I want it do, but now, I want to add some more features.

**What I want to achieve**

Okay, so in my app, I have a search button. When a user wants to search, he should be able to type an ingredient (like minced beef) and then receive results of recipes containing minced beef. He should also be able to search for a recipe and then get to that recipe, or recipes similar to the one he typed in.

**Scenario 1**. A user searches for an ingredient.

**What should happen** The user should get results on all recipes containg that special ingredient. When the user finds a recipe that he likes, he should be able to click on it and the app should show what ingredients he have at home and what ingredients he needs to purchase.

**Scenario 2**. A user searches or a recipe

**What should happen**. The user gets result on the recipes that matches his search. If he clicks on one, the ingredients that he has should show (as in Scenario 1) and the ones he needs to purchase should also show, also as in scenario 1.

**The question**

How should I, as efficiently (in terms of execution time) as possible set up the databases to be able to display information from different databases with one search. I found this http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/recipes/index.htm, from what I'm guessing that I will need multiple databases. 
I do not need help to code the setting up phase, but merely how the structure of databases should be designed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually need multiple databases? It's tables displayed there (http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/recipes/index.htm), but not separate databases. Probably you can start with creation of java objects and their relations.

Comment: I don't really know, but I guess that I do not need multiple databases, but only multiple tables within that database. Thanks for the imput. I will edit my question to add this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to have multiple databases to store objects of your application model. You may want to consider using the following (or something similar) domain model classes for your app and have the corresponding tables in the database:

```
public class Recipe {
    int id;
    String name;
    String source; // Mom, A friend's name, A website url, a magazine name, etc.
    Date lastUpdated; // When the recipe was added/updated
    ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients; // A list of ingredients used by this recipe 
}

public class Ingredient {
    int id;
    String name;
    String preferredSources; // a store name, a friend's name :), etc.
    ArrayList<Recipe> recipes; // A list of recipes which use this ingredient
}

public class RecipeIngredient { // Join class for many-to-many relationship
   int recipeId;
   int ingredientId;
}

public class Inventory {
    int ingredientId;
    int location; // locker, fridge, freezer, etc.
    float quantity; // in weight, count, etc.
    Date lastUpdated; // When the last replenishment was done
}
```

Since you have a many-to-many relationship between Recipe and Ingredient objects, I am suggesting creating a join class RecipeIngredient. The Inventory class is for the ingredients you currently have at home.

Your searches may happen against Recipe and Ingredient classes (tables). Once you get the corresponding ingredientId(s), you may search your Inventory for the availability of those ingredients at home.

After shopping for Ingredient items, you should update the Inventory class (table). Also, after an ingredient is used up, you should update its Inventory quantity.

To simplify the development effort including automatic database schema (tables) creation for your app, you may consider using an ORM like [JDXA](http://www.softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html). Here are some [code snippets](http://www.softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/mapping_many_2_many.html) for handling many-to-many relationships with JDXA.

Comment: I'm not sure why I should use JDXA. Do I still need to use databases/tables while using JDXA? What exactly does it do and what actions can you perform? I cannot find any proper documentation, other than their pretty scarce forums.

Comment: JDXA will use the SQLite database and its tables but you as a programmer would be using the underlying data in a more intuitive object oriented way by using JDXA APIs.  Essentially, JDXA will help you easily save and retrieve your domain objects (Recipe, Ingredient, Inventory, etc.) along with the relationships without you having to write low-level code involving SQL. Various links on the website including code-snippets explain the product at a high level. You may download the SDK, which comes with much more documentation including a comprehensive manual, javadocs, and many sample projects.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. It seems though, that JDXA will cost me money after 30 days, which leads me to believe that I'm better off with another ORM-system, like SugarORM or something. It seems very easy, although I don't know if it is any good.

Comment: Well, JDXA is a fairly non-intrusive and flexible ORM. Yes, there is small one-time fee but I believe it would more than pay for itself if it saves you even a couple of hours of your valuable time.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct, due to the fact that it pointed me in the direction of ORMs, which has helped me huge to solve this matter. I have found a ORM that works for me at the moment (SugarORM), but if it falls short further ahead, I will consider JDXA.

Comment: Thank you. Here is a [link](http://www.softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/download-jdxa.php) to get a Free 30-day trial version of JDXA ORM.